# Duplicate entry '...' for key 'PRIMARY' during the transaction

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, transactions

This one happened to me last night. I am quite familiar with the nature of the error but still I cannot figure out what could have caused it. I might have a hunch, but I am not sure. I'll begin with some basic app's info:

My app has 3 entities: `Loan`, `SystemPage` and `TextPage`. Whenever someone adds a loans, one or more system pages is being added to the DB. Basically, it goes something like this:

```
if ( $form->isValid()){
    $this->em->getConnection()->beginTransation();
    $this->em->persist($loan);
    $this->em->flush();

    while ($someCondition){
        $page = new SystemPage();
        //... Fill the necessary data into page
        $page->setObject($loan);
        $this->em->persist($page);
    }

    $this->em->flush();
    $this->em->getConnection()->commit();
}
```

*<sub>Please ignore potential typos, I am writing this literally by remembering</sub>*

Entity `Loan` is mapped to table `loans` and `SystemPage` is mapped (via inheritance mapping) to `system_pages` and `base_pages`. Both of later one have `id` field which is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

My hunch: There is another table called `text_pages`. Given that `text_pages` and `base_pages` on one hand and `system_pages` and `base_pages` on another **share IDs**, I am thinking that it could easily cause this:

```
User1: Create BasePage, acquire autoincrement ID (value = 1)
User2: Create BasePage, acquire autoincrement ID (value = 1)
User1: Create TextPage, use the ID from step 1
User2: Create SystemPage, use the ID from step 2
```

Two problems with this theory:

- Transactions. That's why I used them in the first place
- In the time of error there was no other activity on app by another user

**Important: After waiting for a minute, resubmitting passed OK.**

Could this be some weird `MySQL` transaction isolation bug? Any hint would be greatly appreciated...

### Edit:

Part of DB Schema:

[image]

<sub>*Please ignore the columns names which are in Serbian language*</sub>

Comment: Trying to keep primary keys of multiple tables in sync is always a bit iffy.  I can't explain exactly what happened unless you have a redirect of some sort between creating the base page and the other page but life is short.  Give each table their own auto-increment primary key and use a regular foreign key to link the two.

Comment: Some questions about this: Which entry caused the bug, Systempage? Have you some kind of rollback in case of an error? If you just fill one entity for each loop, why do you use transaction and not just flush? And last can you ensure, that this was the only request during that time, even from the same user (double submits by double clicks or something similar)?

Comment: Cerad, yes, it definitely is iffy :) The thing is, tables `base_pages`, `text_pages` and `system_pages` already have their `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields set. That actually might be the root cause of the problem. I could try debugging the issue and seeing which query executes first (`base_pages` or `system_pages`) and then remove auto increment on later one. But total random occurrence (only once so far) really makes it difficult to be confident that it fixed anything :)

Comment: CiTNOH, I believe `rollback` is a default behavior in case of error. Otherwise, there were not manually issued `rollback` calls. The idea for transactions was to make sure that the `Loan` could not be created and `SystemPage` was not. One entity without another should not be valid. As for the double submits, I can see how that could be an issue, but shouldn't  the execution stop on `beginTransaction()` if one is already active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flush() operation flushes all changes in one single transaction, so you have redundant code here...

You didn't stated if you can reproduce this bug and it would be convenient if you can provide db schema.

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce the bug. It was in fact very isolated error. My my understanding was that `commit` without `flush` does nothing (when within transaction). Is that correct?

Comment: See second paragraph: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html - if you do not have explicitly stated in your code begin/commit/rollback, flush will persist your changes in single transaction, therefore, your logic regarding transaction in code, as far as I can see, is not required since you do not handle rollback or trans save points.

Comment: If you can not reproduce the bug - the bug does not exist. You have to be able to reproduce it in order to debug it, or we are in very grey area...

Comment: If `base_page` is parent of `text_pages` and `system_pages` in inheritance mapping in Doctrine, text_pages nor system_pages should not have auto incrementing ID - how that happened?

Comment: And if you suspect on some bug in MySQL in regards to auto increment values collision due to concurrent inserts - don't: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: That `AI` on lower level tables is definitely not necessary. I will work on that and watch closely to see if error would reemerge. Truth to be told, I won't know for some time until I hit it.

Comment: And to wrap this question up, thanks :) Transferred the bounty to you ;)

Comment: Also, I corrected my code. After reviewing it, there was a `flush` before while loop and one after ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no right answer to this question, only speculation, so I will provide some troubleshooting ideas based on my own experiences with a problem like this:

1. You mention there was no other activity on the app, but I would triple check that by looking at the query logs.  There must be a duplicate query that was executed.
2. Maybe the form was submitted twice accidentally. The user double-clicked on the submit button, or they clicked again if the UI did not respond.  You can check this idea by looking at the Apache log files for POST requests on your form around the same timestamp.  You may need to implement some javascript code to prevent double-clicks on your form page submit button.
3. Your hunch is probably quite close to correct, in that there is some kind of race condition.  Using transactions won't prevent race conditions, but they do provide the means to gracefully rollback.  Wrap your code in a try/catch block so that you can catch the Mysql exception and present the user with a friendly error and the option to retry.

Comment: Thanks Kris. I can, at least, go though with `try-catch` in order to prevent critical error. As for the extra activity, I looked at server log and there was no evidence of any.